# Where exactly is "Canalcinco" in Argentina?

Tags: identify-this, argentina, buenos-aires

I'm looking at a official translation of a death certificate issued by an Argentinian official in **La Plata** in 1965. The original is not available to me. It specifies the place of domicile of a relative as "**Canalcinco**". There is no space in the name, but possibly could actually be "Canal cinco"? I assume the name refers to an island but I'm not sure about it.

I would like to visit this place but fail to locate it.

What I know is that my relative

- lived on a small private island where he died in 1962 in the **Tigre Delta**
- the island is 85 km from something called "Malteria Hudson" (a brewery possibly)
- the island faced floods but as far as I know only after his death
- he was buried in **Campana**
- the island was affected by surveying works for the "**Canal Irigoyen**" of the "**Vincente Lopez**" council
- during the floods it was a full day trip from Buenos Aires to the island
- a earlier letter said it could easily be reached by boat from Vincente Lopez in 1-1.5 hours.
- there was noone else living on the island as far as I know and it only had a wooden shack housing
- he had neighbors on other islands nearby
- he cut cottonwood on the island

I would greatly appreciate anyone trying to help me locate the island or this place called Canalcinco.

Comment: Cinco means 5. Is there a place where canals are numbered, eg Canal 5?

Comment: @JonathanReez It seems no less travel-related than the stream of "where is this photo?" questions we get.

Comment: @DavidRicherby a photo is much more precise, definitive, and easy to track down.

Comment: Voting to keep open, is not different from the other 'where is' question.

Comment: http://www.welcomedelta.com.ar/casa_islacorina.html this seems very strongly related. Probably not the answer but note it's in the Tigre Delta 400 metres from Channel 5.

Comment: @chx here's more information about Channel 5: http://www.samekprop.com/canal-5-o-canal-seoane-2da-seccion-43-has. Opening Google Maps even shows a nice looking house nearby, which could be OP's ancestral home!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Canal de Riego Numero Cinco links Canal Gobernador De La Serna (itself linked to Rio Paraná Mini and thence to Rio Paraná Guazu) to Arroyo (stream) Los Sauces to the west. As the crow flies about 84 – 89 km from [Maltería Hudson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m58L7fOCM3E) and about 29 km from Campana, the nearest centre of population. Maltería Hudson was an Argentine malt producer owned by [Cervecería y Maltería Quilmes](https://www.cerveceriaymalteriaquilmes.com/) (part of Groupo Bemberg) whose factory at Guillermo Enrique Hudson, Berazategui was demolished in 2001 it is now the site of a tapas bar and restaurant "[La Malteria, Club Cervecero](https://www.facebook.com/pages/La-Malteria-Club-Cervecero/192082064320586)".

Canal de Riego Numero Cinco (Irrigation Canal Number 5) is in Tigre Partido (an administrative subdivision of the province of Buenos Aires) but the town of that name is south and west of the Río Luján so about 32 km by road from the centre of the capital city and about 30 km south of Canal de Riego Numero Cinco.

There is a Canal Martín Irigoyen northwest of Zarate (itself northwest of Tigre) and a road called Vincente Lopez in the town of Tigre but both names are very common in the province.

A property at 34° 7'10.91"S 58°38'22.60"W might be considered to be on an island.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great work! That information is of great help to me!